# Not able to mock a method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have this code i want to test in isolation in some_module.py

```
import tarfile
def function_to_test(path_to_tar):
    tar_file = tarfile.open(path_to_tar)
    for tar_info in tar_file.getmembers():
        #some logic to test
        pass
```

And i can't get to effectively mock tarfile methods so i can mimic a tar file without having to read from actual file, my current attempt looks as follows

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

def test_DeepLabModel_unexistent_error():
    tar_path = "/path/to/nowhere"

    import tarfile

    with patch.object(tarfile, 'open', autospec=True) as open_mock:
        open_mock.getmembers = Mock()
        open_mock.getmembers.return_value = ['a','b']

        from some_module import function_to_test
        function_to_test(tar_path)
        pass
```

This doesn't work, the call to "getmembers" in the test method just returns another MagicMock object and not the list of strings i'm providing, thus not iterating as it should. I've achieved my purpose using similar behavior in the past, but i can't understand why that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `return_value` between `open_mock` and `getmembers`. After you've defined your mock, you need to say what that mocked method is going to return. *That* is what you're going to be calling `getmembers` on in the method you're testing. Your test would look like this:

```
import tarfile
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from some_module import function_to_test

def test_DeepLabModel_unexistent_error():
    tar_path = "/path/to/nowhere"

    with patch.object(tarfile, 'open', autospec=True) as open_mock:
        open_mock.return_value.getmembers.return_value = ['a','b']
        get_members(tar_path)
```

Note that I've moved the imports to the top as well.

Comment: I have other issues now (as expected returned object are TarInfo not just strings) but this works as expected. I had fooled around with import elements cause i was afraid that the issue was due to early imports/initialization

Comment: `>       with mocker.patch.object(tarfile, 'open', autospec=True) as open_mock:
E       AttributeError: __exit__`, any idea?

Comment: @muon I would need a lot more context and details to help. Piggybacking on another question is not the proper way to get the help you need. Please open a new question with more details and I'll see if I can help.